# windows speech recognition lexicon visual basic

Tags: .net, vb.net

My question is about speech recognition and visual basic. I have been making a lot of research in this topic for example : (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.addlexicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), as well in other many sites and forums but I haven't managed to reach a solution.

I have created a project in visual basic as program language that listens to users commands, based on javis examples I found on youtube and forums), and it automatically prompts you to the specific textbox and displays the spoken text. For example : user says 'Name' ,the cursor goes to the textbox name and then the users says 'James',the text is displayed on the textbox.

My question is: I want to speak my native language, which is GREEK and unfortunately it is not supported directly from WSR. I have searched the Microsoft database and came to the conclusion that I have to add it to the WSR dictionary in order to be displayed but this is not done from my gui but from the gui of WSR. Is there any way to override it?

For example, can I have in my visual basic GUI a textbox and a button for adding a word and not having to perform the usual procedure ?:WSR ->advance options->add word->pronounce the word  ?
Or if there is a way to "dock" the windows speech recognition in my form, just like we do with the datagridview.
I can provide you with my code so far if you need it ,but i think my question is straightforward and it is not needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: OK perhaps i was confusing...i can imagine that when i add a word in the WSR and then pronounce it in my native language it is stored somewhere in a file  correct?I want to access that file and include only my new added words for better accuracy excluding the english.That is exactly my question which it answers to my problem.So is there any way to edit that file or access it from my gui application?